# Google Admob working on simulator but build failed in real device

Tags: iphone, cordova, admob

I have added adMob in a phonegap iOS project. It **works fine in simulator** But when I tried to build it in real device it shows me error and build failed.
errors message:

```
duplicate symbol _GAD_MD5 in:
/Users/prium/Documents/phonegap/projects/Diamond-mixer-iOS/GoogleAdmobiOS/llibGoogleAdMobAds.a(md5.o)
/Users/prium/Documents/phonegap/projects/Diamond-mixer-iOS/GoogleAdmobiOS/llibGoogleAdMobAds.a(gad_md5.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help.

Comment: may be you add some file twice check it

Answer (score 0):

check out for Build settings-->architectures-->armv7 and armv7s. JUST put armv7

Answer (score 0):

adding armv7 and armv7s to architecture should work